# Kubernetes RBAC to restrict user to see only required resources on kubernetes dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, authorization, kubectl, rbac, azure-aks

Hi Everyone,
             I want to restrict my developers to be able to see only required resources on kubernetes dashboard(For example only their namespace not all the namespaces). Is possible to do that . If yes can someone point me to the right documents ? Many Thanks

I am using the below RBAC for the `kube-system` namespace. However the user is able to see all the namespaces on the dashboard rather than seeing only the namespaces he has access to.

```
kind: Role     
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1       
metadata:     
  namespace: kube-system      
  name: dashboard-reader-role     
rules:      
- apiGroups: [""]     
  resources: ["service/proxy"]     
  verbs: ["get"]       

---       
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1      
kind: RoleBinding     
metadata:     
 name: dashboard-reader-ad-group-rolebinding      
 namespace: kube-system     
roleRef:     
 apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io       
 kind: Role   
 name: dashboard-reader-role   
subjects:      
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io  
  kind: Group  
  name: "****************"
```

Answer (score 1):

please see the k8s rbac documentation:

example:
create a developer role in development namespace:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  namespace: development
  name: developer
rules:
- apiGroups: ["", "extensions", "apps"]
  resources: ["deployments", "replicasets", "pods"]
  verbs: ["list", "get", "watch"]
# You can use ["*"] for all verbs
```

then bind it:

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: developer-role-binding
  namespace: development
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: DevDan
  apiGroup: ""
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: developer
  apiGroup: ""
```

also , there is a built in view only role that u can bind to user:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#default-roles-and-role-bindings

```
C02W84XMHTD5:~ iahmad$ kubectl get clusterroles --all-namespaces  | grep view
system:aggregate-to-view                                               17d
view                                                                   17d
```

but this is clusterwide view role , if you want them to see only the stuff in a specific namespace only then create a view role in that namespace and bind it , exmaple above.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . But i am talking about the permissions for kube-system namespace. Even if i mention only services in resources of the role, every thing is showing up on the dashboard

Comment: in your question u asked: For example only their namespace not all the namespaces)

Comment: you can do the same for kube system namespace , but u need to create a role and proper role binding

Comment: ---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: kube-system
  name: dashboard-reader-role
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["service/proxy"]
  verbs: ["get"]

---  
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
 name: dashboard-reader-ad-group-rolebinding
 namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
 apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
 kind: Role
 name: dashboard-reader-role
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Group
  name: "***********"

Comment: I created above for the kubesystem. But when the user login to the dashboard. he is able to see all the namespaces which he does not access also.